# Updating variable on main class out of scope from Event Handler Method

Tags: c#, events

The event listens to Tick Data (Stock close-price) that is publishing an update every second. I can see this using the console.Writeline.

I want to get the close price, and add it to a List in my main class. However, it looks like the the tickList variable is out of scope. Regardless of the access modifier I use.

Not sure If tackling the problem correctly. I tried using a multitreaded approach, but the first return of close price stops the thread so I can't see to get subsequent rate updates. Any advise guys?

Here is the main class code.

```
class Program
{
     List<Data> tickList = new List<Data>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SamplePattern runSamplePattern = new SamplePattern();
        TickData runPublisher = new TickData();

        runPublisher.TickUpdated += OnTickUpdated;

        runPublisher.PublishTickData();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OnTickUpdated(object source, TickEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Close);
        Data close = new Data();

        // I am trying to add the close price to a list called tickList 

    }
}
class Data
{
    public double Close { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your methods all are `static` you need to create your `tickList` as a `static` field, too:

```
class Program
{
     static List<Data> tickList = new List<Data>();
```

If you ommit the `static` keyword, the `tickList` becomes an *instance* member of `Program`. But your methods are `static` and so don't have an instance of `Program`.

---

For more information see [`static` in the C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).